# How to convert the Mat with two channels into a vector<vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, vectorization, mat

If I have a mat like

```
Mat mat = (Mat_<int>(1, 8) << 5, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1, 9, 9);
```

Of course I can convert `mat` into a vector `vec` by

```
vector<int> vec(mat.begin<int>(), mat.end<int>());
```

But when the `mat` have 2 or more channels, how to convert it into a  `vector<vector<int>>`?  I mean if I have such `mat`

```
int vec[4][2] = { {5, 6}, {0, 4}, {0,1}, {9, 9} };
Mat mat(4,1,CV_32SC2,vec);
```

How to get a `vector<vector<int>> vec2{ {5, 6}, {0, 4}, {0,1}, {9, 9} }`？ Of course we can traverse very pixel like this

```
vector<vector<int>> vec2;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Vec2i*p = mat.ptr<Vec2i>(i);
    vec2.push_back(vector<int>());
    vec2[vec2.size() - 1].push_back(p[0][0]);
    vec2[vec2.size() - 1].push_back(p[0][1]);
}
```

But any better method can do this?

Comment: In general, I would store any matrix in a single `std::vector` (instead of nested vectors). The double sub-script is IMHO "syntax sugar" and can simply be reduced to something like `iRow * nCols + iCol`. For multi-channel matrices, two solutions come in mind: either using a `struct` as vector element or making a "3 dimensional" matrix as vector with the same addressing trick as above: `(iRow * nCols + iCol) * nChans + iChan`.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to use a vector with size [numPixels][numChannels] instead of [numChannels][numPixels] ? Because the latter one would be much easier to achieve with split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet for type CV_32SC3 image:

```
cv::Mat image = imread("picture.jpg");
cv::Scalar scalar[3] = { { 255, 0, 0}, { 0,255,  0 }, { 0, 0, 255 } };
Mat channel[3];
vector<vector<int>> splitted_images;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    channel[i] = image & scalar[i];
    vector<int> vec(channel[i].begin<int>(), channel[i].end<int>());
    splitted_images.push_back(vec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for a Mat with 2 or more channels

```
vector<int> vec1, vec2;
//we can convert the 2 channel image into a single channel image with 2 columns
mat.reshape(1).col(0).copyTo(vec1); //to access the first column
mat.reshape(1).col(1).copyTo(vec2); //to access the second column


//Or like this (if you know the number of channels
vector<vector<int>> vec(2);
mat.reshape(1).col(0).copyTo(vec[0]); //to access the first column
mat.reshape(1).col(1).copyTo(vec[1]); //to access the second column


//You can make them into a vector of points like this
vector<Point> pts;
mat.copyTo(pts);
```